# Apache file ownership and envvars

Tags: apache2, php, ownership

I use Ubuntu 20.04. I have edited `/etc/apache2/envvars` to change the run user to `userA`: `export APACHE_RUN_USER=userA`

When I run [this PHP script from W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) to upload a file, the upload works - but the owner of the file is not `userA` as I intend.  It remains `www-data`.

Yet:
`sudo apache2ctl -S` reports `User: name="userA" id=1002`, as set in envvars.

So why does `www-data` own the file, and not `userA`?  What is determining file ownership? FWIW, the permissions of the directory into which the file is uploaded are `774`, and ownership is `userA:www-data`.  "Set UID" and/or "Set GID" on the directory had no impact either.

If I drag and drop a file in the directory with WinSCP (using ssh), the ownership is `userA:userA` (yes, `userA` is a member of both the `userA` group and `www-data` group). If I Set GID and drag and drop, the owner is `userA:www-data`.

Comment: Did you restart the Apache process entirely?  (`sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl restart apache2.service`)  If you haven't then it won't have loaded everything 'new' nor will it have restarted the processes to run as `userA`

Comment: Check the `htop` output and set it to "tree" format in the htop setup - check what the subprocesses of Apache are running as - `userA` or `www-data` as well.

Comment: I did stop it entirely - I even resorted to rebooting, to no avail.  But I also posted this to StackOverflow, they suggest I should be looking at php-fpm, which sets permissions and ownership independent of apache:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67892965/ubuntu-20-04-apache-file-ownership-and-envvars

Comment: How'd you install PHP to begin with?  Normally people just use the PHP that's bundled inside Apache.  If you have `php-fpm` set up then that's something we need to know because FPM *isn't* the default PHP mechanism in Apache.  And there's no way to determine if you are or aren't unless you share your configs with us.

Comment: @ThomasWard, all of the apache processes are running as userA (except for one as root).  There are several www-data processes running, all as www-data.  In running phpBB, I have had occasion where I've needed to switch between different PHP versions in different environments - so I've followed the instructions listed here:  https://devanswers.co/run-multiple-php-versions-on-apache/

Comment: I am also running Ubuntu.  This article states that PHP does *NOT* come bundled with apache: https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/installing-php-for-apache-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Um... it depends on how you install it.  Apache2 doesn't come with Apache by default, yes, however MOST people install the Apache PHP plugin rather than using php-fpm with Apache, because it's simpler.  (Fun fact: it goesback to the statement I made of "It depends how you installed PHP")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126285/discussion-between-shortmort37-and-thomas-ward).

Answer (score 1):

So, this will depend heavily on how you do your PHP.

There's two typical approaches to this with Apache, and each have different considerations to fix this issue with permissions.

---

**Embedded `php` module in Apache**

This is the simplest solution to get Apache to work with PHP.  PHP runs within Apache, and runs as the Apache configured user.

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php
sudo a2enmod php
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

---

**PHP FPM**

PHP FPM is the other option - you would install the `php-fpm` package, but you'll also need extra work with Apache to make it work.

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-fcgid php-fpm
```

You then need to enable the FCGId module in Apache, as well as the `alias` and `proxy_fcgi` modules:

```
sudo a2enmod actions fcgid alias proxy_fcgi
```

For Ubuntu 20.04, PHP is 7.4, so you will need to add this to your server configuration wherever you're using `php-fpm`:

```
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        # 2.4.10+ can proxy to unix socket
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
```

This must be within your `<VirtualHost ...>` blocks wherever you're using PHP.

You then must adjust `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` to make it use the user you intend to - look for the `user = www-data` line, and adjust this to the user you want.  I would comment this line out and then put your user defined one underneath it, but that will change the user in use by `php-fpm` for it to read/write with.

---

Either of these approaches will fix your PHP user/group that it writes/creates files with - it just depends how you install PHP - Apache embedded module, or FPM.

Comment: Thank you, @ThomasWard.  I favor running PHP within Apache; I've made an attempt to apt remove php-fpm (and purge), but it still appears to be running.  A subsequent remove attempt reports that it is not installed, so that's puzzling.  I've even rebooted, but htop reports it running.  In any event:  I attempted to follow the embedded PHP instructions.  "sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php" went smoothly, but the a2enmod command reports "ERROR: Module php does not exist!"  I am thoroughly confused now.

Comment: `sudo apt purge 'php*-fpm'` might help remove the FPM components.  `php-fpm` is a metapackage, pulls in `php7.4-fpm` on Ubuntu, so you need to do a more broad purge.  Or just purge `php7.4-fpm`.

Comment: quite right!  That purge eliminated fpm, it no longer appears in htol.  All is now well.  Many thanks!